# How to read binary file as float with ifstream and istreambuf_iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, floating-point

I read a binary file to a uchar vector like this:

```
std::ifstream is("path", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char> fileVector((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is)),
                                       std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

But now I want to read bytes (4 adjacent bytes) into float and create a vector of floats. There is no `std::istreambuf_iterator<float>`. How do I do that?

Comment: You can't do it because four successive bytes aren't necessarily a valid float value.

Comment: @JamesKanze, they are. I'm sure.

Comment: You can't be sure, because there's no way you can write such a file.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I recommend to take a look at [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module with which you can pack binary data with an exact size.

Comment: And what does packing have to do with it?  Within a single process, you can `memcpy` at will.  As soon as you want to write the data to disk, and read it later, or to stream it over a serial line, you must define a format, and interpret it.  (Note that the Python `struct` module will only work on systems where Python is implemented, _and_ it still requires you to specify some parts of a format.)

Answer (score 2):

```
void read_feature(std::ifstream& feature_file,float* features) {
  feature_file.seekg(5*sizeof(int));
  feature_file.read((char*)features, 4096*sizeof(float));
}
```

with this code, you can read a float array of 4096 elements, starting from the data excluding the first 5 integers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinterpret cast `char *` to `float *` and dereference. This is not a common task so it seems you should use some hack like this

```
for(int i=0;i<fileVector.size();i+=sizeof(float))
{
    float f=*((float*)&fileVector[i]);
    out.push_back(f);
}
```

Comment: This is very non-standard, may work on your machine but will surely break on other platforms. You could consider converting your float to a string and then store it in your file.

Comment: The question was, "I want to read bytes (4 adjacent bytes) into float", not "How useful is it"

Comment: Answer works. The proof: http://ideone.com/XCGSZo Note: if you have something to say, 1) think, 2) say nothing

Comment: @DmitryIlukhin why so complicated? why not simply `ifs.read((char*) &float_ptr, sizeof(float));`

Comment: @Vallentin idk maybe because I prefer safe container operations instead of raw reading into buffer that could cause buffer overflow and other bad things

Comment: @DmitryIlukhin Huh? I'm not sure I follow. `read()` as far as I know won't overflow and you can check `eofbit`, `failbit`, `badbit` if `read()` as done successfully, or you could check `tellg()` before you `read()`.

Comment: I've changed the description to match the code. `static_cast` isn't what the C cast is doing there